# selenium grid - api for listing all available nodes

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Is there an available API method for listing and getting information for all registered nodes for a Selenium Hub.

I can use /grid/api/proxyid=nodeurl:5555 to get a particular nodes information, but can't seem to find a way to list all available nodes.

I've seen a function in the source "getAllProxies" but don't see an api implementation of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open ticket for this.  In the meanwhile, you can build and contribute your own servlet.  I've done this to provide a customized version of this API for node monitoring within Mogotest.

Comment: Has there been any update on the ticket?  Do you happen to have the ticket number?  I'd love to check the status.  I'd like to have a better option than navigating to the grid hub url and scrape text from the screen.

Comment: Do you have the ticket number or link?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure why I never linked the ticket -- that's unlike me. But in the meantime Selenium has transitioned from Google Code to GitHub and the old issue track seems inaccessible. The issues were [imported](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/), but I couldn't readily find the issue. You're probably better off opening a new issue against the GitHub project.

Answer (score 0):

You can build yourself a Selenium powered method which checks

```
http://localhost:4444/grid/console
```

and lists all nodes and possible sessions

Shouldn't be that hard

Comment: you mean running a selenium script to check the selenium grid page and grabbing the info from there? I guess that would work but not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: that's the easiest way I can think of ;)

Comment: Tried it.. but when the node is busy, it's garbage for parsing.